# React Framer Motion whileInView not working while using X position

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to use whileInView in order to animate some elements on scroll in react.

here is the codesandbox link: https://bz6msx.csb.app/

if you go and check the code then you see that while using whileInView it does not trigger the animation.

is there anything am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you received an answer to this, [here.](https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1546#issuecomment-1140486490)

> That is not bug. whileInView property is associated with Intersection
> Observer API. In your CodeSandBox , h1 tag has initial state with x:
> 100vh. h1 tag not visible in viewport. only visible element activate
> whileInView animation.
>
> There are some tricks.
>
> set 100vw to 95vw. Then element is visible.

```
 <div className="App">
  <motion.h1
    initial={{
      x: "95vw" // set 100vw to 95vw
    }}
    // This is not working
    whileInView={{
      x: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 1,
        type: "spring",
        stiffness: 50
      }
    }}
  >
    Motion
  </motion.h1>
</div>
```

> ```
> Set WhileInView Property parent tag.
> ```

```
import "./styles.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [isInView, setIsInView] = useState(false);
  return (
    <motion.div
      whileInView={() => {
        // when element in viewport , set IsInView true!
        setIsInView(true);
        return {};
      }}
      className="App"
    >
      <motion.h1
        initial={{
          x: "100vw"
        }}
        // This is working
        animate={
          isInView && {
          x: 0,
          transition: {
            duration: 1,
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 50
          }
        }}
      >
        Motion
      </motion.h1>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```